# Losing original exception message in rollback exception strategy on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded

Tags: java, error-handling, mule, mule-el

I have a rollback exception strategy in place which looks for a message queue full scenario.
The issue I am facing is when the `maxRedeliveryAttempts="3`" is exhausted, `on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded` code is executed but inside the `on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded` block, the original exception message and its `reasonCode` are lost.

Can you please suggest/advice what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the rollback exception strategy.

What can be done to workaround this is to store the original exception into the object store and retrieve it within the on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded when needed.